# How do I prevent the Undefined offset:1 Error Exception in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code for importing excel data in my Controller

```
$row['cast'] = "Directed by:Tracie Pang;Written by:Dennis Kelly;Starring:Pinky Amador,Thomas Pang,Tess Pang,Salif Hardie";

$cast_types = explode(";", $row['cast']);
foreach ($cast_types as $cast_type) {
    $cast = explode(":", $cast_type);
    $cast_type_name = $cast[0];

    // if there is more than 1 cast name
    if (strpos($cast[1], ",") !== false) {
        $cast_names = explode(",", $cast[1]);
        $cast_names_str = implode("<br>", $cast_names);
    } else {
        $cast_names_str = $cast[1];
    }
```

$cast[1] will look something like "Tracie Pang" or "Pinky Amador,Thomas Pang,Tess Pang" (managed to see it also by running dd($cast[1]) ) but Laravel throws me an "Error Exception : Undefined Offset 1" here

```
if (strpos($cast[1], ",") !== false) {
```

How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if the array key exist using array_key_exists function to prevent the error

```
$row['cast'] = "Directed by:Tracie Pang;Written by:Dennis Kelly;Starring:Pinky 
Amador,Thomas Pang,Tess Pang,Salif Hardie";

$cast_types = explode(";", $row['cast']);
foreach ($cast_types as $cast_type) {
 $cast = explode(":", $cast_type);
 $cast_type_name = $cast[0];

 // if there is more than 1 cast name
 if (array_key_exists(1, $cast)) {
    $cast_names = explode(",", $cast[1]);
    $cast_names_str = implode("<br>", $cast_names);
 } else {
    $cast_names_str = $cast[1];
 }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it works! But does that mean that if I wanted to access any element of the array I have to manually check with array_key_exists() ?

Comment: yes, because it will get error if the array key is doesn't exists, or you can give default value, it will prevent the error